# Spring CDF not showing some properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have an app `MyApp` with `MyAppProperties` in one project and `CommonProperties` in another project. Both property classes are annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`. I added `META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties` with the following content in the `MyApp` project:

```
configuration-properties.classes=com.app.MyAppProperties, \
  com.common.CommonProperties, \
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties, \
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties$Pool, \
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties$Sentinel
```

I have also added this dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

But when I click on the little wheel in the CDF stream creation GUI I can see `MyAppProperties` and all the `RedisProperties` but not any of the `CommonProperties`.

I get the same result with `app info --id processor:myapp` from `dataflow-shell`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to verify the correctness of assembly would be to refer to any of the OOTB apps that have a similar setup.

For instance, the `time-source` (*also: `jdbc`, `file`, and may others*) pull [`app-starters-trigger-common`](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/time/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-time/pom.xml#L23) as a dependency to inherit common "trigger" [application properties](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/core/blob/master/common/app-starters-trigger-common/pom.xml) from a different project altogether.

With this and having `TriggerPropertiesMaxMessagesDefaultOne` [whitelisted](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/time/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-time/src/main/resources/META-INF), you're able to list both native and the dependent artifact properties.

Perhaps in your case, you may not have the right dependency lined up to consume `CommonProperties` from the other project.

Comment: I think I do, I can pass my `CommonProperties` to the app via DSL, e.g.`: --common.value=5` and actually see it at the `MyApp` startup so the dependency is working, it just isn't showing it as available.